# Extract JSON value using Jmeter

Tags: json, jmeter, extract

I have this JSON:

```
{
  "totalMemory" : 12206567424,
  "totalProcessors" : 4,
  "version" : "0.4.1",
  "agent" : {
    "reconnectRetrySec" : 5,
    "agentName" : "1001",
    "checkRecovery" : false,
    "backPressure" : 10000,
    "throttler" : 100
  },
  "logPath" : "/eq/equalum/eqagent-0.4.1.0-SNAPSHOT/logs",
  "startTime" : 1494837249902,
  "status" : {
    "current" : "active",
    "currentMessage" : null,
    "previous" : "pending",
    "previousMessage" : "Recovery:Starting pipelines"
  },
  "autoStart" : false,
  "recovery" : {
    "agentName" : "1001",
    "partitionInfo" : { },
    "topicToInitialCapturePosition" : { }
  },
  "sources" : [ {
    "dataSource" : "oracle",
    "name" : "oracle_source",
    "captureType" : "directOverApi",
    "streams" : [ ],
    "idlePollingFreqMs" : 100,
    "status" : {
      "current" : "active",
      "currentMessage" : null,
      "previous" : "pending",
      "previousMessage" : "Trying to init storage"
    },
    "host" : "192.168.191.5",
    "metricsType" : { },
    "bulkSize" : 10000,
    "user" : "STACK",
    "password" : "********",
    "port" : 1521,
    "service" : "equalum",
    "heartbeatPeriodInMillis" : 1000,
    "lagObjective" : 1,
    "dataSource" : "oracle"
  } ],
  "upTime" : "157 min, 0 sec",
  "build" : "0-SNAPSHOT",
  "target" : {
    "targetType" : "equalum",
    "agentID" : 1001,
    "engineServers" : "192.168.56.100:9000",
    "kafkaOptions" : null,
    "eventsServers" : "192.168.56.100:9999",
    "jaasConfigurationPath" : null,
    "securityProtocol" : "PLAINTEXT",
    "stateMonitorTopic" : "_state_change",
    "targetType" : "equalum",
    "status" : {
      "current" : "active",
      "currentMessage" : null,
      "previous" : "pending",
      "previousMessage" : "Recovery:Starting pipelines"
    },
    "serializationFormat" : "avroBinary"
  }
}
```

I trying using Jmeter to extract out the value of agentID, how can I do that using Jmeter, what would be better ? using extractor or json extractor?

what I am trying to do is to extract agentID value in order to use it on another http request sample, but first I have to extract it from this request.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) is the best way to get this `agentID` value, the relevant JsonPath query will be as simple as `$..agentID`

Demo:

[image: JMeter Json Extractor Demo]

See the following reference material:

- [JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started) - for initial information regarding JsonPath language, functions, operators, etc.
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) - for more complex scenarios.

Comment: And if I want to use code in order to parse the json how can I do that using jmeter?

Comment: You can add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns above JSON and put the following line into "Script" area: `log.info("agentID: " + com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString()).read('$..agentID')[0])`. It will print "agentID" value into *jmeter.log* file. See [Parsing and producing JSON - Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and [Groovy is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) articles for more details.

Comment: Thanks but what I meant was can I add java code which will parse json strings?

Comment: Groovy is Java-compatible so you can treat above as plain Java code (actually it doesn't use any Groovy syntax features)